# Configure CQP (CRF) for h264_nvenc

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, nvidia

Encoding on CPU can be done via:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -crf 23 -acodec copy h264.mp4
```

GPU's alternative for the codec is `h264_nvenc`. How can I pass the same options to it?

---

I googled and came to following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264_nvenc -rc constqp -qp 23 -acodec copy h264_nvenc.mp4
```

But the file I get is much larger. And with other options quality is much worther.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/943877/178988)

Answer (score 3):

CRF != CQP. The former may have variable QP but tries to maintain quality. CQP is a cruder form of rate-control.

For nvenc, use `-rc vbr_hq -qmin 0` and add `-cq X` where X sets a quality level; range is 0-51. Smaller is better.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264_nvenc -vcodec h264_nvenc -cq 1 -acodec copy 25962-1.mp4` with values 0, 1 and 23 produce the same binary file having bad quality. With 51 file is 3 times smaller and quality is worther. So the parameter is not ignored.

Comment: Edited cmd. Values below 26 will produce about the same quality.

Comment: No, still bad quality.

Comment: nvenc will not match x264 quality at the same bitrate.

Answer (score 2):

from reading:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc
```

and the nvidia nvenc examples at (https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/), I've arrived at:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i test_input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 0 -cq 1 test3.mp4
```

where:

```
-b:v 0 over-rides the default 2mbps bitrate as noted by Gyan
-cq 1 means target quality level 1 (highest)
 range of 0-51. 
 0 means automatic (in my case around 15mbps)
 1 gives about 15mbps, 26 results in around 5mbps, 51 results in 0.5mbps
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify bit rate yourself, FFmpeg will assume a default bit rate of 256 kbit\s, you have to unset it with `-b:v 0`.

Comment: The `h264_nvenc` encoder has a default bitrate of 2 mbps. But in any case, the `cq` mode does not look at bitrate.

Comment: Can you show the full command, please?